# Where is the teardrop shaped amethyst (#5) in Gloomy Manor?

Tags: luigis-mansion-dark-moon

In *Luigi's Mansion: Dark Moon* I have all the Gloomy Manor gems, save for one: The teardrop shaped amethyst. Without getting too spoiler-y, what room is it in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one is the most obscure of all the gems in Gloomy Manor. It can be found in the Entrance starting in A-3.

> Tap the knight on the right to have it disgorge it's treasure, then vacuum up the helmet. Aim the helmet at the painting of the helmet on the left (a green crosshair will appear). Fire away to get the gem!